# How can I make cells in CollectionView fit all the space they can in 2 columns?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

This is code for collectionview with 2 columns, I understand that GridItemsLayout makes it impossible to achieve "cells" fitting under each other, but if I use LinearItemsLayout it will make collectionview has one column.

```
           <CollectionView
               x:Name="notesView"
               Margin="15">
               <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                   <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Span="2"
                                    VerticalItemSpacing="10"
                                    HorizontalItemSpacing="10"/>
               </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
               <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                           //irrelevant
                   </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           </CollectionView>
```

Right now, my CollectionView has 5 items, and it looks like this:

[As you can see, height of "row" is dependent of the highest item in column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRQAQ.png)

But I'd like to make them "fit" in any possible space, just like that:

[As you can see, here items are under each other despite height of other item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCli.png)

As I said before, I tried making LinearItemsLayout but with it I can't achieve 2 columns, I don't have idea what I can do next.

Comment: Actrually, this is the Maui design in the `CollectionView.ItemsLayout`.  However, you can change the [item size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout#item-sizing).

Comment: Try using FlexLayout inside Collection View. It works fine in these scenerios